# How to exclude two conditions in query via Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-filter

How can I exclude by two conditions which are connected via a logical OR:

```
Object.objects.filter(country_send=country).exclude(status__exact='').order_by('-id')
Object.objects.filter(country_send=country).exclude(status__exact='deleted').order_by('-id')
```

I'm trying to exclude the object with no status and status "deleted".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try using "lists". On status list you can add all the words you want.

```
status = ['deleted', '']
Object.objects.filter(country_send=country).exclude(status__in=status).order_by('-id')
```

More about list: http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/

Answer (score 30):

Have a look to [Q Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Your query will be:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Object.objects.filter(country_send=country).exclude(Q(status__exact='') | Q(status__exact='deleted')).order_by('-id')
```

Answer (score 14):

You might consider chaining `exclude` calls together:

```
Object.objects.filter(country_send=country).exclude(status='').exclude(status='deleted').order_by('-id')
```

This has the affect acting like an `or` operator, and is more readable than using the `Q()` Object.

The "list" approach from Marcos above is likely best in your case, but my approach would be useful if you are "or-ing" on different fields:

```
Book.objects.exclude(author='Joe').exclude(publish_year='2018')
```

This will return all `Books` and exclude the ones that are either authored by Joe, *OR* published in 2018.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using Q

```
from django.db.models import Q
Model.objects.filter(country_send=country, ~Q(status__in=['deleted', ''])).order_by('-id')
```

Comment: This code has SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument